# Text field is not accepting blank space as a character

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery 1.9.2 version. When validating a field(Not Required) for Minimum length on submit, a text field is not considering "white space" as a character. Minimum length is not validated unless a character is entered into that field. Is this because of jQuery version am using or any other problem?

Comment: It depends entirely on how you are validating the field, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Ji, am asking why a text field is not accepting a blank space as a character when validating for MinLength.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited I read that wrong)

You can check the length of the value before submit with:

```
$('#element').val().length() >= someMinimum
```

Make sure you don't get and undefined.